# Can walking provide electrical energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, electricity, everyday-life

This is more of a theoretical question, but is it possible to convert the energy you use to walk into electrical energy to say, power a light bulb?

Comment: As an addition to John Rennie's answer, there is a university near where I live that has a rec center with its elliptical machines set up to feed power to the building. When people walk on them, they provide energy. Quite a cool concept.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and in fact there are several types of electrical chargers that you power by walking. Typically you'd use these for low power applications such as recharging your mobile phone as you walk.

There are a lot of frankly daft designs out there, but [this one](http://www.militaryaerospace.com/articles/2012/10/power-generating-backpack.html) is being funded by the US military, which may or may not be daft depending on your views of the military. Note that all these chargers produce only small amounts of power otherwise they would make it too hard to walk. You could not power a light bulb unless it was an exceedingly small light bulb.

See also:

https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/764467377/solepower-power-by-walking-0

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/nn405175z

and many, many other easily Googlable articles.

Comment: thanks for that, how does the energy transfer work between the walking and the battery?

Comment: @Vishwa Iyer there are many ways of turning the kinetic energy of jostled objects into electricity, such as with piezoelectric crystals or electromagnetic induction (magnets near coils). The trick is to make sure the system only pumps the battery rather than discharges it, for which the use of diodes is key. The details of particular designs could probably be hashed out on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/